# Unable to answer own question, forced to verify my humanity if in edit mode > 2? mins

Tags: support, asking-questions

I've worked for my company for 5 years, had several laptops, used various browsers include IE and the latest Chrome and have always had issues using this site using my company machine.

The most annoying issue is that I have to type my questions in notepad and the paste them in and quickly assign tags and post it. If I were to keep the SO edit editor up for more than a couple of minutes, or probably much less, I would get a posting error and on subsequent retries, be forced to verify my humanity.

I also have get errors trying to answer my own question.

The site works pretty well from my home PC. What can be causing this? We are a monkey see monkey do company, surely we must not be unique.

If you want more info, step me through it.

Comment: Odd, I've always heard people had the opposite issue: pasting question being too quick and triggering the captcha. What does the page look like when this happens? Maybe your work internet has been blacklisted because the IP address was used by a botnet?

Comment: Any browser add-on or plugin supplied by your company? Or maybe some proxy/VPN configuration..?

Comment: I think @Kyll is on the right track with suggesting there may be a proxy or VPN connection involved. Very common in company provided laptops,

Comment: “Monkey see monkey do company” meaning your company acquires behaviours by copying without understanding? Do you mean their infrastructure is out-of-the-box without proper requirements analysis? Could you be more explicit about what your company and its infrastructure are like?

Comment: I'm sure that means they copy what other companies do and don't do anything exotic. But surely, OP, you could write your stuff up in a text editor other than Notepad.

Comment: I read "monkey see monkey do" to mean their developers just copy code from Stack Overflow for all their development.

Comment: Unrelated suggestion: *stop using Notepad*. Upgrade to Notepad++ or something.

Comment: @Laurel I interpreted this question to be more about the "posting error" than about the CAPTCHA, which seems more like a side effect of this.  Maybe the OP can clarify with the other clarifications requested.

Comment: @MichaelGaskill If that was intended to be the focus of the question, there should have been more details about the error instead of the Captcha. We don't have enough information to know if the [error is a teapot](http://meta.retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/114) or not.

Comment: @Laurel Agreed.  I was actually pointing out that this is not necessarily a duplicate of the CAPTCHA post.  (Too many reviewers see "possible duplicate", interpret that as "researched and verified 100% to be a duplicate" and treat it as such.)  As you say, without more information, it's impossible to determine exactly what this is, teapot or otherwise.

Comment: I hit the "There was an error posting" followed by "Prove you're human" today; the first time in four years of posting.  Thought I had been hacked.  Glad to know it's just a misguided automated system that really doesn't like people using their preferred editor to type up a post.

Comment: FYI, there are some IPs that you log in from that have over 100 (one even has > 200) distinct active users...

Comment: Network load balancing? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Load_Balancing

Comment: I just wanted to be clear that I only resorted to using notepad because keeping the browser window open with SO's editor in edit mode was problematic. I only diverge from the normal path because of the issue with SO and not some desire to find a "better" editor, just one that works. Using Notepad was inconvenient but it works. There's no need to suggest better alternate editors than notepad like Notepad++ above was suggested-that is missing the point. So, if SO worked for me, I wouldn't be using any editor.

Comment: @ChadD I'm guessing that you've tried posting at home or a library i.e. a non company-networked computer? If not please do so. I'm betting it goes without a problem. Chances are your company uses a VPN or proxy of some sort or is otherwise blocked at the IP level on SO. I don't know how to fix that - a mod might.

Comment: correct, it works from home always

Comment: @ChadD As I said, it was unrelated to your problem. Although, in general, writing up your question or portions of it outside of the website is pretty normal. Additionally, you're a professional software developer; we do plain text editing *every day*. Try something better. I think once you get exposed to the feature set a tool like Notepad++ offers, you won't be able to stand Notepad anymore and will come to the conclusion that "works" isn't even a word you'd use to describe it. That is the experience most developers seem to have. (In other words, I'm only trying to improve your life. ;) )